# hg serve - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: mercurial

I'm sure that there are several reasons as to why this could occur, but I found one of them: I use a Sony VAIO and when 'VAIO Care' is installed and running on your machine, it blocks port 8000 and causes this error to occur whenever you attempt to 'hg serve' one of your repositories. Specifically, manually terminating VCsystray.exe caused this error to cease when executing an 'hg serve'. Thought I should pass along this information in the event that anyone else was running into the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for passing the information along — your "question" will be closed soon, but others will be able to find it in the future and so the information wont be lost.